# How to read xml file from queue and modify it by c#?

Tags: c#, xml

How can I load Xml file into queue then read the file and add Header and footer then save it.

Comment: Either use the "older" [XmlDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) to load the entire XML into memory, or use [Linq-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387023.aspx) to manipulate your XML

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class to manipulate XML files in .NET. For example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
doc.Root.AddFirst(new XElement("header", "the header value"));
doc.Root.LastNode.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("footer", "the footer value"));
doc.Save("test.xml");
```